# How can I do joins given a threashold in Hadoop using PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

Let's say I have a dataset with following schema:

```
ItemName (String) , Length (long)
```

I need to find items that are duplicates based on their length.  That's pretty easy to do in PIG:

```
raw_data = LOAD...dataset
grouped = GROUP raw_data by length
items = FOREACH grouped GENERATE COUNT(raw_data) as count, raw_data.name;
dups = FILTER items BY count > 1;
STORE dups....
```

The above finds exact duplicates. Given the set bellow:
a, 100
b, 105
c, 100

It will output 2, (a,c)

Now I need to find duplicates using a threshold.  For example a threshold of 5 would mean match items if their length +/- 5.  So the output should look like:

3, (a,b,c)

Any ideas how I can go about doing this?

It is almost like I want PIG to use a UDF as its `comparator` when it is comparing records during its `join`...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do what you want is to load the data into two tables and do a cartesian join of the data set onto itself, so that each value can be compared to each other value.

Pseudo-code:

```
r1 = load dataset
r2 = load dataset
rcross = cross r1, r2
```

rcross is a cartesian product that will allow you to check the difference in length between each pair.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar problem once and got one crazy and dirty solution.
It is based on next lemma:

```
If |a - b| < r then there exists such an integer number x: 0 <= x < r that
floor((a+x)/r) = floor((b+x)/r)
```

(further I will mean only integer division and will omit floor() function, i.e. 5/2=2)

*This lemma is obvious, I'm not gonna prove it here*

Based on this lemma you may do a next join:

```
RESULT = JOIN A by A.len / r, B By B.len / r
```

And get **several** values from **all** values corresponding to |A.len - B.len| < r

But doing this **r** times:

```
RESULT0 = JOIN A by A.len / r, B By (B.len / r)
RESULT1 = JOIN A by (A.len+1) / r, B By (B.len+1) / r
...
RESULT{R-1} = JOIN A by (A.len+r-1) / r, B By (B.len+r-1) / r
```

you will get **all needed values**. Of course you will get more rows than you need, but as I said already it's a dirty solution (i.e. it's not optimal, but works)

The other big disadvantage of this solution is that JOINs should be written dynamically and their number will be big for big **r**.
Still it works if you know **r** and it is rather small (like r=6 in your case)

Hope it helps